# Story / Trailer about Tom Clancy's The Division where [spoiler] happens

Tags: episode-identification, trailer, the-division

I remember watching a trailer (perhaps live-action?) for *The Division*, where a lady asks a sanitation worker for help with her [brother?]. The sanitation worker asks if her brother is sick and when the lady responds that her brother is sick, he makes a call and tells her to stay where she is.

Several moments later, a garbage truck with a group of armed sanitation workers show up and gun her down.

---

Can anyone help identify this story / trailer? I've been looking all over for it, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this Agent Origins video by Corridor Digital:

Comment: Yep, that's the one! I didn't realize that there were different _Agent Origins_ videos, but that explains it. Thanks!